# Is the vector contained in the null space of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, vectors

Is the vector **b** contained in the null space of **A**?
\begin{align}
A & =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -3\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 6 \\
3 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 8 \\
\end{bmatrix},
& b= & 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 9 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

I am confused because vector b has a higher dimension then the matrix A, so I can't just multiply them and check if I am getting a 0 vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right; the product $\bf Ab$ does not exist because of the wrong dimensions. So $\bf b$ cannot be in the null space of $\bf A$.

There might be a typo: suppose that the given vector is actually ${\bf b}^T$. In that case, we can multiply it by $\bf A$, but even then, the first row of the resulting product is $21$, not $0$, so we can stop our calculations there and conclude that the answer would again be no.